Calculating $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\Big[{\frac{1}{1+f(x)}}\Big]$ from the quotient rule
I am trying to write a formula for $$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\Big[{\frac{1}{1+f(x)}}\Big]$$ for an infinitely differentiable function $f$.
By the quotient rule I can compute: $$\frac{d}{dx}\Big[{\frac{1}{1+f(x)}}\Big]=\frac{-f'(x)}{(1+f(x))^2},$$
$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\Big[{\frac{1}{1+f(x)}}\Big]=\frac{-f''(x)(1+f(x))^2+2(f'(x))^2(1+f(x))}{(1+f(x))^4},$$
and
$$\frac{d^3}{dx^3}\Big[{\frac{1}{1+f(x)}}\Big]=\frac{-f'''(x)(1+f(x))^6+6f''(x)f'(x)(1+f(x))^5-6(f'(x))^3(1+f(x))^4}{(1+f(x))^8},$$
so the formula should look something like$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\Big[{\frac{1}{1+f(x)}}\Big]=\frac{-f^{(n)}(x)(1+f(x))^{2n-2}+...+...+c(n)(-1)^n(f'(x))^n(1+f(x))^{2^n-n}}{(1+f(x))^{2^n}}$$ for some constant $c$ depending on $n$.

Use Faà di Bruno's formula

use Leibnitz rule

You will need to know $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}f(x)^m$ which can simplify for given $f(x)$. If not, likely the  Faá di Bruno formula is best then.

Reduce the second derivative, to have denominator $(1+f(x))^3$.  In general, the $n$th derivative will have denominator $(1+f(x))^{n+1}$.

For simplicity, I will call $f(x)$ as $y$
Let $g(x)=\frac{1}{1+y}=(1+y)^{-1}$
$$g(x)=1-y+y^2-y^3+\cdots$$
$$\implies g(x)=\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}(-1)^r y^r$$
Now you can derive a formula for the nth derivative.
